# Determine Difference Value with Rollovers

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have the following table:

```
 id | location_id | datetime            | value1 | value2 
 ---------------------------------------------------------
  1 |         123 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 |  10000 |   5000
  2 |         123 | 2014-09-01 00:05:00 |  15000 |  10000
  3 |         123 | 2014-09-01 00:10:00 |  20000 |  15000
  4 |         123 | 2014-09-01 00:15:00 |  25000 |  20000
  5 |         123 | 2014-09-01 00:20:00 |   5000 |   1000
  6 |         123 | 2014-09-01 00:25:00 |  10000 |   5000
                   .....
 99 |         123 | 2014-09-01 23:55:00 |  90000 |  30000
100 |         123 | 2014-09-02 00:00:00 |  95000 |  35000
  x |         123 | 2014-09-02 00:05:00 | 100000 |  40000
                   .....
  x |         999 | 2014-09-01 00:00:00 |  50000 |  30000
  x |         999 | 2014-09-01 00:05:00 |  55000 |  35000
```

The value columns will always increase for a given location_id, except when a rollover happens (in which case the value starts from zero again)

This table will have a row every 5 minutes for hundreds of different location_ids.
Notice there is a rollover in the value columns starting at ID 5.

I want to get the difference in the value columns for each day for each location_id, given a set of dates (ex/ 2014-08-01 - 2014-09-01).

To get the desired values for location_id 123 on date 2014-09-01, I would need to account for the rollover.  It would be (using value1 as an example):

```
90000 (row id 99 - ending value) + 25000 (row id 4 - rollover value) - 10000 (row id 1 - starting value) = 105000
```

The result would look something like this:

```
location_id | date       | value1 | value2
------------------------------------------
        123 | 2014-09-01 | 105000 |  45000
        123 | 2014-09-02 |  90000 |  50000
        123 | 2014-09-03 |  70000 |  35000
        999 | 2014-09-01 | 100000 |  90000
        999 | 2014-09-02 |  80000 |  60000
        999 | 2014-09-03 |  70000 |  50000
```

This result would show a daily difference for each location_id, for each date specified in the query.

Any ideas on how to attack this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming the value after the rollover will always be less.

This query numbers the value by date using `row_number` and uses conditional aggregation to add or subtract the last, first and rollover values.

```
select
    location_id,
    date(datetime) date,
    sum(case 
        when rn_datetime_desc = 1 then value1 
        when rn_datetime_asc = 1 then (value1 * -1)
        when next_value1 < value1 then value1
        else 0 
        end) value1
from  (
    select 
        location_id, datetime, value1
        lead(value1) over (partition by date(datetime) order by datetime asc) next_value1,
        row_number() over (partition by date(datetime) order by datetime asc) rn_datetime_asc,
        row_number() over (partition by date(datetime) order by datetime desc) rn_datetime_desc
    from mytable order by datetime asc
) t1
group by location_id, date(datetime)
```

Comment: This is great, thanks.  I added duplicate sections to account for the same processing of value2, and it works well.